# How do you pronounce "to me" and "to you" quickly at the end of a sentence?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

I usually hear people pronounce "to me" as "tomi" and "to you" as "toyo". Am I hearing it correctly? If not, what's the correct pronunciation?

Here's some examples:

- Sounds great to me.
- Can I talk to you?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pronunciations i would suggest, based on my experience, are "t'mē" (or "t'mi") and "t'yoo" (or "t'yə").

Answer (score 0):

The pronunciations suggested by @fertilizerspike are going to be broadly correct for most English speakers, but...

The exact pronunciation will vary depending on the speaker's regional accent, and also according to how and when they choose to place emphasis on particular words.

A casual 'sounds fine to me' is usually going to sound something like 't'me', but if the speaker were emphasising something, they'd pronounce the 'to' more like it is spelled. 'To' can also change depending on whether it's being used before a vowel or not. 'T'mi' or 'Towour' for 'to our'.

There's a good video by Dr Geoff Lindsay here about the subject with audio examples here: https://youtu.be/EaXYas58_kc